# Explain a Substitution

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am solving a volume integral of the form:
$$
\int f(|\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{r})|)d^3 r
$$
The textbook gives a hint about substitution as follows:

"
Hint: Consider the symmetry of the integrand. If an integrand is spherically symmetric about $\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$, the substitution $d^3r = 4 \pi |\mathbf{v}|^2d|\mathbf{v}|$ can be performed.
"

Could you explain what the hint is saying to me?

Answer (score 0):

The function depends only upon the distance (radius) from the origin.  Thus you should perform spherically symmetric integration:

$$\int\limits_{r=0}^\infty f(|{\bf v}|) 4 \pi |{\bf v}|^2 d|{\bf v}|$$

[image]

Comment: But in the hint the substitution is from $d^3r$ to $4 \pi |\mathbf{v}|^2d|\mathbf{v}|$ while your substitution is from $d^3v$ to $4 \pi |\mathbf{v}|^2d|\mathbf{v}|$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Aren't they the same?

Comment: I am not sure. Here $\mathbf{v}$ is a function of $r$ so I don’t see how we can perform the substitution that the hint suggests?